# How to get bot to mention multiple members same time after command

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

So im trying to make command which uses express post to get live statues and when status is something it should send message and mention the member who used the command and tell the status, but in example if two member used it same time it mentions two times the last member who used the command. So how can i make it to mention both members?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0pa9.png)

```
if(command === "test") {

    var user = message.author.username;

    twilio.calls.create({
        url: `${config.ngrok}/call`,
        to: number,
        from: from,
        statusCallback: `${config.ngrok}/status`,
        statusCallbackMethod: 'POST',
        statusCallbackEvent: ['initiated', 'ringing', 'answered', 'completed'],
    })

    app.post('/status', (req, res) => {     
        var status = req.body.CallStatus;     
        message.channel.send(`Status: ${status}, ${user}`)  
    })

}
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can see what is going on and help you out

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a few assumptions because you haven't shared any code but something along these lines should work:

```
client.on('messageCreate', message => {

     if (message.content != '.test') { return }

     message.channel.send('Mention ' + message.author.username)
})
```

Comment: So when the command is used it uses express post to get live statues and when status is something it should send message and mention member who used the command. But in example if two members used the command same time it mentions two times the member who last used it so how it can be made to mention right person?

`app.post('/status', (req, res) => { 
   var status = req.body.Status; 
   message.channel.send(Status: ${status}, ${message.author.username}) 
})`

Comment: @user18684356 Are you able to edit your original post and include the entire code for the command?

Comment: added entire code